# How to replace all white spaces in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have strings which could have single, double or triple white spaces which I want to replace with a comma ','

I have used **.replace(' ', ',')** like so

```
white_space  ="this has white spaces"          #this has white spaces
white_space_replaced = white_space.replace(' ', ',') #this,has,white,spaces

double_white_space  ="this  has  double  white  spaces" #this  has  double  white  spaces
double_white_space_replaced = double_white_space.replace(' ', ',') #this,,has,,double,,white,,spaces
```

But I want to only replace the white spaces with a single comma.  How can I cater for multiple sizes of whitespaces  in python3?

Comment: `','.join(white_space.split())`

Answer (score 0):

Use This, This may work for your case: :)

```
",".join(double_white_space.split(" "))
```